# Image format which is editable as plaintext

Tags: image

I'm trying to find an image file format which features plaintext editable source code. So far in my searches i've found text-in-image scanning with output in plaintext, But that's not what i'm after.

My project is intended to create fractal images using seed integers derived from the binary content of an audio file. I have a solution for the first part. I seem to recall an image format which used tables of hexadecimal pairs to describe a 256 color palette in plaintext source.

A way to convert an image to a space delimited text file table of hex pairs and back again would probably get me past this wall.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SVG is not an option?

Comment: You could use NetPBM and edit in a text editor https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format You can convert between that and JPEG or PNG or anything else with **ImageMagick**. `convert input.ppm output.jpg`

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to find. Thank you.

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project. Remember questions are free, so come back and ask more if you get stuck.

Comment: Note that if you want to convert from JPG, PNG or GIF to NetPBM, you must specify `-compress none` if you want editable ASCII, e.g. `convert input.gif -compress none editable.ppm`

Answer (score 0):

try **SVG**

> https://picsvg.com/

example in HTML

```html
<!-- `<use>` shape defined ON THIS PAGE somewhere else -->
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
   <use xlink:href="#icon-1"></use>
</svg>

<!-- `<use>` shape defined in an EXTERNAL RESOURCE -->
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
   <use xlink:href="defs.svg#icon-1"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, No. But svg does look useful for other unrelated tasks. I'm trying to recall the solution I used for this 20+ years ago. It was an image file format which viewed similar to a .bmp, .jpg or .gif, But was editable in an ordinary text editor. In text it was hexadecimal (0-9 a-f) pairs, separated by spaces, where each pair represented one pixel of the image. It may be a depreciated format at this point, i'm just not sure.